# Setting the Rootpage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm having trouble setting the rootpage of my Application. I wasn't able to show the right page. The first Mainpage is the default from the start and the second MainPage there is the name of the page that I created. Here's my code.

App.cs

```
   public App()
    {   
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

    }
```

And here is the code of my the page that i want to set as root page.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinDemoApp"
         x:Class="XamarinDemoApp.MainPage"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinDemoApp.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinDemoApp">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
      <ViewModels:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
        HasUnevenRows="True">

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
               FontSize="24"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Department}"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>


</ListView>





</ContentPage>
```

This is the code behind my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   using Xamarin.Forms;
   using XamarinDemoApp.ViewModels;

   namespace XamarinDemoApp
   {
       public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
       {
           public MainPage()
           {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

           }
       }
   }
```

This is the Stack Trace field I get.

```
    [External Code] 
>   0xC in XamarinDemoApp.MainPageMain.InitializeComponent at c:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\XamarinDemoApp\XamarinDemoApp\obj\Debug\XamarinDemoApp.Views.MainPageMain.xaml.g.cs:21,13    C#
    0x9 in XamarinDemoApp.MainPageMain..ctor at c:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\XamarinDemoApp\XamarinDemoApp\Views\MainPageMain.xaml.cs:16,13 C#
    0x9 in XamarinDemoApp.App..ctor at c:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\XamarinDemoApp\XamarinDemoApp\App.cs:14,12  C#
    0x12 in XamarinDemoApp.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate at c:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\XamarinDemoApp\XamarinDemoApp.Droid\MainActivity.cs:20,13    C#
    0x13 in Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2857,4  C#
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: show me your MainPage code behind xaml file

Comment: @Vishnu this is the error Sir. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: @saketkumar Alright sir I'll just edit my post.

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista check the inner exception and the stack trace field of TargetInvocationException for more information. Can you post them here?

Comment: @RadinGospodinov  I'll just edit my post sir and Add the stack Trace field.

Comment: Can you post  ViewModels.MainViewModel code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the wrong place ...

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

It should be

```
public App()
{   
    var mainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    MainPage = mainPage;

}
```